# Read access only applet in a dynamic enviroment

Tags: java, permissions, applet

I have moved on to make my first applet and was zooming thru everything faster then i anticipated and now i have hit a snag.  The applet is designed to work in a dynamic environment where it will read a specific folder and all of the files in the sub-folders in that folder.  The problem I am having is that once it is established on my test server it gives:

```
access denied("java.io.FilePermission" "\basefolder" "read")
```

My research has told me that this is because applets in particular are untrusted to begin with.  Unfortunately solutions there are a many i have tried a few but none of which seem to work.  I am currently using eclipse for creating my applet.  So if i am trying to make an applet that reads and displays information on a website from a dynamic folder on a file server what is the best way to grant these permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ..what is the best way to grant these permissions?

The problem is not exactly as you expect.  The bottom line is that an applet cannot create a `File` object on a server (for e.g. to get the file list of a directory).  That is not because of permissions, but just the way that files & servers work.

To get the file list will require help from the server.  And by 'help' I mean the server providing a file list that the applet can read.

If the server is set up to provide the list, and the applet is hosted from that server, it requires no special or extra permissions.

Comment: sigh well though this is bad news i can finally stop banging my head on my keyboard and start fixing the problem. thx